# Invert a sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sequence

I want to invert this sequence:
Invert a function like in mathematics(is this exist in programming)
What I mean: if f(x)=y --->g(y)=x so g is the inverse function of f.
My attempt was(but still not working):

```
function seq(num) {
  
  if(num < 2) {return 1; }
  if(num === 2) {return 2; } 
  
  if(num % 2 === 1) {
    const t = (num - 1) / 2;
    return seq(t - 1) + seq(t) + 1;
  }
  
  const t = num / 2;
  return seq(t) + seq(t + 1) + t;
  
}
document.write(_.invert(seq(4)));
```

Comment: You can't do this in general.  Many (probably most) functions do not have inverses.  Just think of the simple `const square = (n) => n * n`.  What would you expect `invert (square_ (25)` to return?  It could be `5` or `-5`, and there's no reasonable way to decide.

Comment: Your function returns `1` for all numbers less than 2. So what should `inverse_seq(1)` return?

Comment: "*My attempt was*" - I only see the `seq` definition. Where's the attempt? Do you refer to `_.invert`? What is that function?

Comment: My new attempt: function ```mosaeai(q) { var t;                                              
   if (typeof t != "undefined") { seq(t)===q;}                         
    return t}```

Answer (score 1):

There is no known algorithm to programmatically invert a function, baring brute force over the domain. Indeed, such an algorithm, if workable would be a stunning discovery, likely breaking the vast majority of cryptosystems. There are a bunch of different methods for finding the inverse of a function, but they depend on the function in question meeting specific criteria.

The lodash invert function performs an completely different function, swapping keys and values of objects.